# Firestore Sub Collection Query Not Working in Production

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

The code below runs as expected in our development firebase project but will not return any results in 
our production project. The functions, triggers, document structures, indexes appear to be identical for both projects. We must be missing something small.

The firestore query that is having the issue loading all existing documents within the "module2Attempts" subcollection is here:

```
admin.firestore().collection("users").doc("jcGP0aE2RSf0f0vmR15LGa6QNIu1").collection("module2Attempts")
    .get()
    .then(function (docs) {
      if (docs.empty) {
        console.log("No docs found from query.");
        return [];
      }
      let prevAttempts = [];
      docs.docs.forEach(function (doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        prevAttempts.push(doc.data());
      });
      console.log(prevAttempts.length+" attempts found!");
      return prevAttempts;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("Error loading module 2 attempt docs: ", error);
    });
}
```

We have confirmed data.uid is not null or undefined and multiple documents do exist at the collection path defined by the query.

functions/index.js

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const prodServiceAccount = require("./prodServiceAccountKey.json");
const devServiceAccount = require("./devServiceAccountKey.json");

const config = process.env.REACT_APP_STAGE === "prod" ?
  {
    credential: admin.credential.cert(prodServiceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://...."
  } :
  {
    credential: admin.credential.cert(devServiceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://..."
  };

admin.initializeApp(config);

const onCreateModule2Attempt = require('./Modules/onCreateModule2Attempt.js');


// Listen for new module2Attempt docs created
module.exports.createModule2Attempt = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}/module2Attempts/{attemptId}')
  .onCreate(onCreateModule2Attempt.handler);
```

onCreateModule2Attempt.js

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');


exports.handler = async (snap, context) => {
  const data = snap.data();
  console.log("This log is just a test balloon")
  console.log("New Module 2 Attempt for ", data.email);

  admin.firestore().collection("users").doc("jcGP0aE2RSf0f0vmR15LGa6QNIu1").collection("module2Attempts")
    .get()
    .then(function (docs) {
      if (docs.empty) {
        console.log("No docs found from query.");
        return [];
      }
      let prevAttempts = [];
      docs.docs.forEach(function (doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        prevAttempts.push(doc.data());
      });
      console.log(prevAttempts.length+" attempts found!");
      return prevAttempts;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("Error loading module 2 attempt docs: ", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: My guess is that your security rules are the issue. Do you have an error message by any chance?

Comment: Not in the function logs unfortunately. I thought that would be the culprit as well but we did a diff check comparing the dev security rules and prods rules and they match.

Comment: Your code isn't checking for errors at all.  You should catch() on the promise to determine if the get failed.

Comment: I can run the same query on the client side app without an issue as well

Comment: Apologies it was taken out to shorten the code for the post...I do have a catch that isnt being triggered....catch(function (error) {
              console.error("Error loading module 2 attempt docs: ", error);
            });

Comment: So, what *is* being triggered?  Your question is kinda just saying "it doesn't work" without saying what it does do, and how that differs from your expectations.

Comment: When a new document is created in a user's sub collection "module2Attempts" it triggers the cloud function "createModule2Attempt " thereby invoking the onCreateModule2Attempt.js script / cloud function. This script is responsible for processing all of the documents contained within that user's module2Attempts sub collection. However, the script cannot retrieve any of the user's documents in the sub collection. The script works perfectly in the Dev project but will not return a single document in the sub collection in the production project and provides no errors in the functions log.

Answer (score 1):

`exports.handler` isn't returning a promise that resolves when all the work is complete.  This is a [requirement](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) by Cloud Functions, so it knows when it's safe to clean up your work.  If it works sometimes and not others, then what you're observing is a race condition.

Minimally, what you should be doing is this:

```
return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc().collection().get()...
```

Note the return statement.